# How to stack elements of a character list in R

Tags: r

I have 3 character lists that I would like to stack.

I've tried rbind(), rbindlist(), bind_rows() but I'm not achieving the correct final structure.

My original character lists look like this:

```
list1 = list("16403074 L3 2", "16603059 L3 2")
list2 = list("0 1", "0 1")
list3 = list("1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183" ,"1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137")
```

I'd like the final output to look like this:

```
"16403074 L3 2"
"0 1"
"1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183"
"16603059 L3 2" 
"0 1"
"1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137"
```

So the corresponding elements of each list are stacked.

Comment: Use `unlist(c(list1, list2, list3))`

Comment: @clemens, it does a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each list is of the same length, we may use

```
unlist(matrix(c(list1, list2, list3), , 2, byrow = TRUE))
# [1] "16403074 L3 2"                "0 1"                          "1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183"
# [4] "16603059 L3 2"                "0 1"                          "1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137"
```

where the trick is in first constructing

```
matrix(c(list1, list2, list3), , 2, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1]                           [,2]                         
# [1,] "16403074 L3 2"                "16603059 L3 2"              
# [2,] "0 1"                          "0 1"                        
# [3,] "1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183" "1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137"
```

Alternatives would be

```
unlist(do.call(rbind, list(list1, list2, list3)))
unlist(data.table::rbindlist(list(list1, list2, list3)))
```

Comment: unlist(do.call(rbind, list(list1, list2, list3))) did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unnest()` from `tidyr`, part of the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

list1 = list("16403074 L3 2", "16603059 L3 2")
list2 = list("0 1", "0 1")
list3 = list("1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183" ,"1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137")

data <- tibble(strings = c(list1, list2, list3))

data %>%
 unnest()
```

Comment: `unnest()` is in `tidyr`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this -

```
> cat(paste(unlist(c(list1, list2, list3))), sep="\n")
```

OR

```
> writeLines(paste(unlist(c(list1, list2, list3))), sep="\n")

16403074 L3 2
16603059 L3 2
0 1
0 1
1.7 0.75514 -1.62403 0.06183
1.7 0.42851 0.52817 0.08137
```

Comment: No I was looking for the first element of each list to be stacked and then the second element of each list to be stacked...